# Renaming a file with an en dash in the name in C++

Tags: c++, file

In the project I'm working on, I work with files and I check if they exists before proceeding. Renaming or even working with files featuring that 'en dash' in the file path seems impossible.

```
std::string _old = "D:\\Folder\\This – by ABC.txt";
std::rename(_old.c_str(), "New.txt");
```

here the _old  variable is interpreted as D:\Folder\This û by ABC.txt 
I tried

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
//and
setlocale(LC_ALL, "C");
//or    
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
```

but none of them worked.. What should be done?

Comment: Use the Unicode or UTF-8 hex constants for the hyphen in the C++ source code.  You're relying on your C++ code editor to figure out what `-` actually is, so all of those "setlocale" calls will do nothing for you if the compiler interpreted that character differently.

Comment: What if you replace the `–` with `"\xe2\x80\x93"` (utf8)?

Comment: have you tried `u8"This – by ABC.txt"` ?

Comment: I tried this out, but i got those strange symbols
[Image Here](http://anorangeleaf.com/img.png)

Answer (score 0):

The [Windows ANSI Western](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding has the Unicode n-dash, U+2013, “–”, as code point 150 (decimal). When you output that to a console with active code page 437, the original [IBM PC character set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), or compatible, then it's interpreted as an “û”. So you have the right codepage 1252 character in your string literal, either because

- you're using Visual C++, which defaults to the Windows ANSI codepage for encoding narrow string literals, or
- you're using an old version of g++ that doesn't do the standard-mandated conversions and checking but just passes narrow character bytes directly through its machinery, and your source code is encoded as Windows ANSI Western (or compatible), or
- something I didn't think of.

For either of the first two possibilities

***the `rename` call will work***.

I tested that it does indeed work with Visual C++. I do not have an old version of g++ around, but I tested that it works with version 5.1. That is, I tested that the file is really renamed to `New.txt`.

```
// Source encoding: UTF-8
// Execution character set: Windows ANSI Western a.k.a. codepage 1252.
#include <stdio.h>      // rename
#include <stdlib.h>     // EXIT_SUCCESS, EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string>       // std::string
using namespace std;

auto main()
    -> int
{
    string const a = ".\\This – by ABC.txt";    // Literal encoded as CP 1252.
    return rename( a.c_str(), "New.txt" ) == 0? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Example:

```
[C:\my\forums\so\265]
> dir /b *.txt
File Not Found

[C:\my\forums\so\265]
> g++ r.cpp -fexec-charset=cp1252

[C:\my\forums\so\265]
> type nul >"This – by ABC.txt"

[C:\my\forums\so\265]
> run a
Exit code 0

[C:\my\forums\so\265]
> dir /b *.txt
New.txt

[C:\my\forums\so\265]
> _
```

… where `run` is just a batch file that reports the exit code.

---

If your Windows ANSI codepage is not codepage 1252, then you need to use your particular Windows ANSI codepage.

You can check the Windows ANSI codepage via the `GetACP` API function, or e.g. via this command:

```
[C:\my\forums\so\265]
> wmic os get codeset /value | find "="
CodeSet=1252

[C:\my\forums\so\265]
> _
```

The code will work if that codepage supports the n-dash character.

This model of coding is based on having one version of the executable for each relevant main locale (including character encoding).

---

An alternative is to do everything in Unicode. This can be done portably via Boost file system, which will be adopted into the standard library in C++17. Or you can use the Windows API, or *de facto* standard extensions to the standard library in Windows, i.e. `_rename`.

Example of using the experimental file system module with Visual C++ 2015:

```
// Source encoding: UTF-8
// Execution character set: irrelevant (everything's done in Unicode).
#include <stdlib.h>     // EXIT_SUCCESS, EXIT_FAILURE

#include <filesystem>   // In C++17 and later, or Visual C++ 2015 and later.
using namespace std::tr2::sys;

auto main()
    -> int
{
    path const old_path = L".\\This – by ABC.txt";    // Literal encoded as wide string.
    path const new_path = L"New.txt";
    try
    {
        rename( old_path, new_path );
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch( ... )
    {}
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

To do this properly for portable code you can use Boost, or you can create a wrapper header that uses whatever implementation is available.

Comment: If the program requires running with a specific locale, it is a bad program. Don't put this into production code. P.S. Why don't just use `int main()`?

Comment: @AndreyNasonov: The model is bad, the programs are not necessarily bad (they're just very limited). It is unfortunate that that's the model inherent in the C++ standard library, and the C standard library, and the selection of execution character encoding for Visual C++ compiler. It's so for historical reasons.

Comment: @AndreyNasonov: I finally added a "use Unicode!" opinion at the end. I think we're roughly on the same page there. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the operation system. In Linux file names are simple byte arrays: forget about encoding and just rename the file.

But seems you are using Windows and file name is actually a null-terminated string containing 16-bit characters. In this case the best way is to use `wstring` instead of messing with encodings.

Don't try to write platform-independent code to solve platform-specific problems. Windows uses Unicode for file names so you have to write platform-specific code instead of using standard function `rename`.

Just write `L"D:\\Folder\\This \u2013 by ABC.txt"` and call `_wrename`.

Answer (score -1):

It really platform dependant, Unicode is headache. Depends on which compiler you use. For older ones from MS (VS2010 or older), you would need use API described in MSDN. This test example creates file with name you have problem with, then renames it

```
// #define _UNICODE // might be defined in project
#include <string>

#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

// Convert a wide Unicode string to an UTF8 string
std::string utf8_encode(const std::wstring &wstr)
{
    if( wstr.empty() ) return std::string();
    int size_needed = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    std::string strTo( size_needed, 0 );
    WideCharToMultiByte                  (CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), &strTo[0], size_needed, NULL, NULL);
    return strTo;
}

// Convert an UTF8 string to a wide Unicode String
std::wstring utf8_decode(const std::string &str)
{
    if( str.empty() ) return std::wstring();
    int size_needed = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), NULL, 0);
    std::wstring wstrTo( size_needed, 0 );
    MultiByteToWideChar                  (CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), &wstrTo[0], size_needed);
    return wstrTo;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[] ) {
    std::string pFileName = "C:\\This \xe2\x80\x93 by ABC.txt";
    std::wstring pwsFileName = utf8_decode(pFileName);

    // can use CreateFile id instead
    HANDLE hf = CreateFileW( pwsFileName.c_str() ,
                      GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                      0,
                      0,
                      CREATE_NEW,
                      FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                      0);
    CloseHandle(hf);
    MoveFileW(utf8_decode("C:\\This \xe2\x80\x93 by ABC.txt").c_str(), utf8_decode("C:\\This \xe2\x80\x93 by ABC 2.txt").c_str());
}
```

There is still problem with those helpers so that you can have a null terminated string.

```
std::string utf8_encode(const std::wstring &wstr)
{
    std::string strTo;
    char *szTo = new char[wstr.length() + 1];
    szTo[wstr.size()] = '\0';
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wstr.c_str(), -1, szTo, (int)wstr.length(), NULL, NULL);
    strTo = szTo;
    delete[] szTo;
    return strTo;
}


// Convert an UTF8 string to a wide Unicode String
std::wstring utf8_decode(const std::string &str)
{
    std::wstring wstrTo;
    wchar_t *wszTo = new wchar_t[str.length() + 1];
    wszTo[str.size()] = L'\0';
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str.c_str(), -1, wszTo, (int)str.length());
    wstrTo = wszTo;
    delete[] wszTo;
    return wstrTo;
}
```

a problem with size of character for conversion.. call to WideCharToMultiByte with 0 as the size of target buffer allows to get size of character required for conversion. It will then return the number of bytes needed for the target buffer size. All this juggling with code explains why the frameworks like Qt got so convoluted code to support Unicode-based file system. Actually, best cost-effective way to get rid of all possible bugs for you is to use such framework.

for VS2015

```
std::string _old = u8"D:\\Folder\\This \xe2\x80\x93 by ABC.txt"s;
```

according to their docs. I can't check that one.

for mingw.

```
std::string _old = u8"D:\\Folder\\This \xe2\x80\x93 by ABC.txt";
std::cout << _old.data();
```

output contains proper file name... but for file API, you still need do proper conversion

Comment: You can't have an UTF-8 locale in Windows, so that UT8- encoded filename will be gibberish.

Comment: **−1** Because this approach will not match a filename as source, or will produce a gibberish filename as result (and the answer was not fixed after I noted that).

Comment: @alf are you sure? NTFS stores names in Unicode. In fact, being russian, I constantly deal with problem - naming file in Russian produces utf-8 filename on NTFS volume. By the way, I didn't found en dash in widechar tables. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317748(v=vs.85).aspx It stores them in UTF-16 though, as I said, you need API to convert it. newer runtime apparently does it under hood? and it doesn't work with fopen and other POSIX functions, they work only with ANSI

Comment: The `rename` operation that the OP is using is (in practice) implemented as a call down to the Windows ANSI compatibility layer. I.e. it expects Windows ANSI encoded strings. UTF-8 encoded strings, or any `char` based encoding that supports n-dash, is fine if one has a rename operation that expects that encoding, but Microsoft doesn't offer one.

Comment: You missed what I said, did you?. **Do not use file access POSIX functions on Windows with Unicode**. Use Win API that uses WCHAR. Not their "POSIX" layer that contains fopen and such. For moving(renaming) file that is MoveFile(). If portability of code required, one need some multiplatform framework, similar to Qt (solution for Qt is almost an one-liner)

Comment: The Windows API rename function that accepts `char` based arguments is the one used by `rename`. It doesn't matter if you call that directly or via `rename`. It requires Windows ANSI encoded arguments, converts them to UTF-16, and calls down to the `wchar_t` based basic function.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf there is _tfopen function by the way

Comment: Updated answer with Win API snippet